# Crop the grid in a numpy array using a polygom cutline

Tags: python, numpy, gis, gdal

How do I crop a [EPSG:25832](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-32n/) raster stored in a numpy array with a [wkt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) polygon?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The thing is; a college of my has written some python scripts, that generate an interpolated maps and now there's a request to crop the image using a cutline. I have been looking at this solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262021/how-to-replicate-gdalwarp-cutline-in-python-to-cut-out-tif-image-based-on-the-e

But then I must have to store my data as temporarily as tiff which is a bit awkward when I  all ready have my data in a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save it in disk, you can use it as temporary object. You can simply use "Mem" format :

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array as gdarr

input_raster = "path/to/rgb.tif" 
# or if the input is already a gdal raster object you can use that gdal object
input_raster=gdal.Open("path/to/rgb.tif")
input_kml = "path/to/cropline.kml" # or any other format

ds = gdal.Warp('',
              input_raster,
              format = 'Mem',
              cutlineDSName = input_kml, # or any other file format
              cutlineLayer = 'extent', # if cutline is a shapefile no need for this cutlineLayer 
              dstNodata = -9999) # select your no data value
#do stuff with ds object, it is your cropped dataset
#for example convert it to numpy array
npDs=ds.gdarr.DatasetReadAsArray(ds, 0, 0, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize)
print(npDs.shape)
```

If you have a numpy array its more tricky because you need to know the geotransform params of that numpy array. My advice is to send back this numpy array to gdal object and then you can do that using gdal.warp()